# Most common consonant sound (token frequency)

Tags: phonology

If the schwa is the most common sound (and vowel sound) in English, it makes me wonder for ages: **what is the most common *consonant sound* in English, in regards to everyday use?**

Comment: I forgot that there were multiple measures (e.g. "how many words contain this?"). I'm looking for: most common in typical usage (speech and writing).

Comment: So I guess that means token frequency? For example, do you want "[a rose is a rose is a rose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type–token_distinction)" to count as having 2 instances of /z/ (one in "rose," one in "is") or 5 (in *rose, is, rose, is,* and *rose*)?

Comment: This source says one estimate found it to be /n/: https://books.google.com/books?id=N5quZxfmpswC&pg=PA143&lpg=PA143&dq=Token+frequency+most+common+English+consonant+phoneme&source=bl&ots=3lAkoh8agL&sig=m-48TUQl8FAumYz1gOzIDf_admA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMIzr2mmJzZyAIVRtJjCh0fbgGs#v=onepage&q=Token%20frequency%20most%20common%20English%20consonant%20phoneme&f=false

Comment: @sumelic: /n/ would have been my guess. Letter frequency is something in the order of e-t-a-i-n-s . . . so it stands to reason that since *t* shows up in digraphs, /n/ would likely be the most common unalloyed sound.

Comment: @sumelic 5 Z's in your sentence. I treat common words like "the" as bumping up the sound's frequency. And thus it's token frequency.

Comment: There is another study that it says it is [n] in spoken text: http://myweb.tiscali.co.uk/wordscape/wordlist/phonfreq.html

Comment: There are also many sources that say that the most common consonant sounds in the world's languages are: /p/, /t/, /k/, /m/, /n/.

Comment: Remember that the online corpora are almost entirely written words rather than transcribed speech. But written language is a reasonable proxy for transcribed. But then any analysis would have to map words (and possibly sentences) to their usual pronunciations.

Comment: "Schwa" isn't a single sound.  It represents a group of similar (but not identical) pronunciations.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://cmloegcmluin.wordpress.com/2012/11/10/relative-frequencies-of-english-phonemes/), the most common consonant sound in the British National Corpus is /n/, closely followed by /r/ (here representing any rhotic) and /t/.

Answer (score 0):

I've asked myself this a lot as well. While the N, R and T sounds are most common according to the British National Corpus, I feel that S sound is more common.

Like a snake hiss. S, X and C make these sounds. You know when we were kids and wound try to speak in another language, or rather just repeat the sounds most prevalent to each language making up gibberish? That's what I would expect other people to who do not speak any English. I hear the S sound most, or it sticks out most anyway. We sound like snakes to others. :)